# Difficulty checking if elements in array are type integer PHP

Tags: php, arrays, validation, isnumeric

I am trying to detect if one or more variables contain numbers. I have tried a few different methods, but I have not been entirely successful. 
Here is what I have tried.

```
<?php
$one = '1';
$two = '2';

$a1 = '3';
$a2 = '4';
$a3 = '5';


$string_detecting_array = array(); 

array_push($string_detecting_array, $one,$two,$a1,$a2,$a3); 

foreach ($string_detecting_array as $key) { 
    if (is_numeric($key)) {
        echo 'Yes all elements in array are type integer.';
    } 
    else {
        echo "Not all elements in array were type integer.";
    }
}

?>
```

I haven't been successful using this method. Any ideas? Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `gettype` if you want to explicitly know if the variable is a number. Using `is_numeric` will not respect types.

If you are intending to use `is_numeric` but want to know if **all** elements are, then proceed as follows:

```
$all_numeric = true;
foreach ($string_detecting_array as $key) { 
    if (!(is_numeric($key))) {
        $all_numeric = false;
        break;
    } 
}

if ($all_numeric) {
    echo 'Yes all elements in array are type integer.';
} 
else {
    echo "Not all elements in array were type integer.";
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response. I have tried this just now and it doesn't seem to work. I have just replaced is_numeric with gettype. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Try `var_dump(gettype($one))` and see if that makes sense.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the example, it was very helpful! Works just how I wanted it to. My logic was clearly all wrong. Thankyou for clearing it up.

Answer (score 8):

First off, your loop logic is wrong: you should process *all* the items in the array before reaching a verdict. The shortest (although not most obvious) way to do this is with

```
$allNumbers = $array == array_filter($array, 'is_numeric');
```

This works because `array_filter` preserves keys and [comparing arrays with `==`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) checks element counts, keys, *and* values (and the values here are primitives, so can be trivially compared).

A more mundane solution would be

```
$allNumbers = true;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (!is_numeric_($item)) {
        $allNumbers = false;
        break;
    }
}

// now $allNumbers is either true or false
```

Regarding the filter function: if you only want to allow the characters `0` to `9`, you want to use [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php), with the caveat that this will not allow a minus sign in front.

[`is_numeric`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) will allow signs, but it will also allow floating point numbers and scientific notation.

`gettype` will not work in this case because your array contains *numeric strings*, not numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You can chain `array_map` with `array_product` to get a one-liner expression:

```
if (array_product(array_map('is_numeric', $string_detecting_array))) {
    echo "all values are numeric\n";
} else {
    echo "not all keys are numeric\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$set = array(1,2,'a','a1','1');  

if(in_array(false, array_map(function($v){return is_numeric($v);}, $set)))
{
    echo 'Not all elements in array were type integer.';
}
else
{
    echo 'Yes all elements in array are type integer.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create own batch testing function. It may be static function on your utility class!

```
/**
 * @param array $array
 * @return bool
 */
public static function is_all_numeric(array $array){
    foreach($array as $item){
        if(!is_numeric($item)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `gettype()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a flag and look at all the items.

```
$isNumeric = true;
foreach ($string_detecting_array as $key) { 
    if (!is_numeric($key)) {
        $isNumeric = false;
    }
}

if ($isNumeric) {
    echo 'Yes all elements in array are type integer.';
} 
else {
    echo "Not all elements in array were type integer.";
}
```