# Using PHP what is the simplest way to check if multiple values are integers?

Tags: php

I know one can likely use the switch statement but I have this currently to check that all function parameters that are supposed to be an int are and if not show an error:

```
if(!is_int($chartWidth)){
   echo "Chart width must be an integer";
}
if(!is_int($chartHeight)){
    echo "Chart height must be an integer";
}
if(!is_int($gridTop)){
    echo "Grid top must be an integer";
}
if(!is_int($gridLeft)){
    echo "Grid left must be an integer";
}
```

Can this be coded any more efficiently or shorter?

Comment: There is no way.

Comment: Why not just cast them to `(int)` and let the user deal with any `0` values generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if these are function parameters as you say, since PHP 5 you have been able to use type hinting for functions. Assuming you expect a value every time you can do the following.

```php
function chart(int $width, int $height, int $top, int $left) {
    // Some code
}
```

If a value passed to the function is a type which is NOT an integer, you will get a fatal error.

Comment: Error depends on `declare(strict_types)`.

Comment: @u_mulder to be exact, [as of php8](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/consistent_type_errors), passing a parameter of illegal type results in a TypeError, regardless of strict_types option.

Comment: @berend - PHP will still coerce things like `foo('1')` and `foo(1.5)` for you unless you use strict types for the paged script.

Comment: Scalar type hints, and return type declarations, were not available until PHP 7.

Comment: @MHewison I see this as the best option as it accomplishes what I intended, it does not adds not extra code and why did i not think of it lol UNFORTUNATLEY it appears I forgot that I am not running PHP 8 yet :-( So my code will have to wait for 8.

Comment: @MHewison I will mark it a the answer for me as I will be using your suggestion in a few next years when we move to 8. thx

Comment: You need at least PHP 7.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function:

```
function assertInt($value, $name)
{
    echo is_int($value) ? '' : $name . ' must be an integer.<br>';
}

assertInt($chartWidth,  'Chart width');
assertInt($chartHeight, 'Chart height');
assertInt($gridTop,     'Grid top');
assertInt($gridLeft,    'Grid left');
```

I don't like the echo inside the function, what if you have multiple variables that are not integers? I therefore added the `<br>` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with dynamic variable names.

```
$chartWidth = 100;
$chartHeight = 200;
$gridTop = '1,2';
$gridLeft = 1.2;

$arr = [
  'chartWidth' => "Chart width must be an integer",
  'chartHeight' => "Chart width must be an integer",
  'gridTop' => 'Grid top must be an integer',
  'gridLeft' => 'Grid left must be an integer'
];

$result = [];
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    if(!is_int(${$k})){
        $result[] = $v;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Grid top must be an intege
    [1] => Grid left must be an integer
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will iterate each variable and if you want to stop or print something before iterate the rest of variables i think it will be the best

```
 $data = array($chartWidth,$chartHeight,$gridTop,$gridLeft);
    
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        echo gettype($value) , "\n";
      if(gettype($value)!="integer"){
         // do something
       }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10418920/5052909